# Enable editors to add an arbitrary number of areas in Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I am using Magnolia CMS 5.3.4.

I want to create a "stacked" page template, in which an editor can add as many "row" areas as she wants in the main area. Each "row" area would contain a list of components.

What would be the easiest / cleanest way to provide this feature?

Defining a great number of row works (e.g., area "row1", area "row2" and so on), but it is tedious to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest areas within components, within areas, etc.

The STK's LinkList component is a good example of this. The [footer link list](http://git.magnolia-cms.com/gitweb/?p=modules/standard-templating-kit.git;a=blob;f=magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit/src/main/resources/templating-kit/components/footer/footerLinkList.ftl) contains [an area](http://git.magnolia-cms.com/gitweb/?p=modules/standard-templating-kit.git;a=blob;f=magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit/src/main/resources/templating-kit/components/links/linkListArea.ftl) that handles the iteration through child nodes usually found in a page template's area. ie.

```
[#list components as component ]
    [@cms.component content=component /]
[/#list]
```

So. Your page template can contain an area, mainArea, that can contain any number of rowComponent items.

Each instance of rowComponent can then contain the markup to ensure it renders as a row, wrapped around an area that renders the child components.

Apply your design to the configuration in the Magnolia demo too:

The [Footer Link List](http://demo.magnolia-cms.com/.magnolia/admincentral#app:stkTemplateDefsApp:browser;/components/footer/stkFooterLinkList:treeview:) would be your row component.

The [Link List Area](http://demo.magnolia-cms.com/.magnolia/admincentral#app:stkTemplateDefsApp:browser;/components/footer/stkFooterLinkList/areas/linkList:treeview:) would be the contents of your row.

And the [Internal and External Links](http://demo.magnolia-cms.com/.magnolia/admincentral#app:stkTemplateDefsApp:browser;/components/links:treeview:) would be the various components you wanted to add within your rows.

Answer (score 0):

we already did exact same for magnolia twitter bootstrap module (go to nexus.magnolia-cms.com and search for twitter-bootstrap-module).

tip: first have available only "row component" which adds only rows to your main and then in every row have availability for other components like text, image, teaser...